Salesforce Tooling Composite API PATCH request giving 404 not found error
Request GET: 
https://....my.salesforce.com/services/data/v56.0/tooling/composite/

I am getting this:
{
  "tree": "/services/data/v56.0/tooling/composite/tree",
  "batch": "/services/data/v56.0/tooling/composite/batch",
  "sobjects": "/services/data/v56.0/tooling/composite/sobjects"
}

I checked which HTTP methods are allowed for /composite/sobjects.
Allowed are POST,PATCH,DELETE
But when I initiate a PATCH request to /services/data/v56.0/tooling/composite/sobjects
it is showing that [ { "errorCode": "NOT_FOUND", "message": "The requested resource does not exist" } ]
What's wrong is here. please help me.
